# Cufon adding itself to everything

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cufon

Cufon is automatically adding itself to the JavaScript AJAX response and the 404 error appears to be breaking the success.

If you go to: http://www.shopfashionablylate.com/handbags/shoulder-bags-and-totes and hover your mouse over a product picture that AJAX is working correctly although when there is cufon on the page it breaks.

I have tried testing this theory by removing the code in the head that is for cufon is it still added to the bottom of the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance of a 'test' page showing the same details but with Cufon?

I'm seeing a couple of errors relating to the JS font file - "Futura-Std_300-Futura_Std_700.font.js" giving a 404; you sure it's uploaded and accessible?

What exactly do you mean by adding itself to the response?

Comment: When you hover over an image if you view this in firebug console you will see that the response is returning the cufon.

Comment: Where's the PHP code that prints the json_encoded object?


Are you `exit(0);`ing afterwards?

Comment: I figured it out, it was a problem where the JavaScript was being inserted via PHP which was annoying.